# ElastAlert error when running rule test typeError: %d format: a number is required, not NoneType

Tags: elasticsearch, elastalert

I am running  example rules under **example_rules** folder , and always get this error:

```
load_entry_point('elastalert==0.0.91', 'console_scripts', 'elastalert-test-rule')()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elastalert-0.0.91-py2.7.egg/elastalert/test_rule.py", line 287, in main
test_instance.run_rule_test()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elastalert-0.0.91-py2.7.egg/elastalert/test_rule.py", line 275, in run_rule_test
hits = self.test_file(copy.deepcopy(rule_yaml), args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elastalert-0.0.91-py2.7.egg/elastalert/test_rule.py", line 54, in test_file
es_client = ElastAlerter.new_elasticsearch(es_config)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elastalert-0.0.91-py2.7.egg/elastalert/elastalert.py", line 143, in new_elasticsearch
send_get_body_as=es_conn_conf['send_get_body_as'])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 150, in __init__
self.transport = transport_class(_normalize_hosts(hosts), **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 113, in __init__
self.set_connections(hosts)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 166, in set_connections
connections = map(_create_connection, hosts)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 165, in _create_connection
return self.connection_class(**kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-  packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_requests.py", line 40, in __init__
  host, port, self.url_prefix
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not NoneType
```

Elastalert config:

es_host: localhost
 es_port: 9200
 use_ssl: False
 name: "Provider slow response"
 type: spike
 index: filebeat*
 threshold_cur: 2
 timeframe:
   minutes: 10
 spike_height: 1
 spike_type: "up"
 filter:
  - query:
      query_string:
        query: "_type: nginxlog"
  alert:
  - "email"

email:
- me@mail.com

Any help?

Comment: How does the relevant Elastalert rule configuration look like?

Comment: I updated with the rule. please have a look. thanks